# I would like to know the correct usage of unexplainable

Tags: synonyms

Their laziness is unexplainable  OR
INEXPLICABLE ?

Comment: What has your research shown, and why do you distrust it?

Answer (score 1):

Inexplicable is used more often to describe aspects of human behavior rather than natural phenomenon but the two are truly interchangeable. You can use either one without fear of correction.

Comment: Yes. Whilst the OED has a substantial entry on *inexplicable*, its entry on *unexplainable* references *inexplicable* and provides only three examples of its use.